# how to use different page design for different category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am absolutely new to wordpress & woocommerce 
my question use different page design for different categories 
eg- for category merchandise use theme's default shop page template & for category music use different custom page design/template 
can anyone help with this

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2):

For overriding default templates please check [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

If you want different/custom category template for specific category then you may create a php file which has naming structure like `taxonomy-product_cat-{slug}.php`. For example, to create custom category template for clothing category, you will need to create `taxonomy-product_cat-clothing.php` where *clothing* is slug of the category. Place this file in the **woocommerce** folder of your theme where you may have overridden other WooCommerce templates. I hope this helps.